# Beverton-Holt population dynamic model

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

I have the model:

$$x_{n+1} =\frac{rx_n}{1+x_n}$$

where $r$ is a positive constant. Using the transformation $y=\frac{1}{x_n}$ show that $y_{n+1}$ is a linear function of $y_n$ and find $x_n$ in terms of $n$.

Can I use that
$y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}$?

Comment: Yes. (What else?)

Comment: @Did When I do this, I get $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{r}(y_n+1)$ and I'm not sure how this helps me find $x_n$.

Comment: The transformation $y_n\to y_{n+1}$ is an affine transformation $y\to ay+b$ and you should be able to iterate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y_{n+1} = \frac{1}{r}(y_n+1) $$
has a simple closed form: set $y_n=z_n+\frac{1}{r-1}$. The recurrence takes the form $z_{n+1}=\frac{1}{r}z_n$, so:
$$ z_n = \frac{z_0}{r^n},\qquad y_n=\frac{z_0}{r^n}+\frac{1}{r-1},\qquad x_n=\frac{1}{\frac{z_0}{r^n}+\frac{1}{r-1}} $$
and at last

> $$ x_n = \color{red}{\frac{(r-1)r^n x_0}{(r-1)+(r^n-1)x_0}}.$$

Comment: Could you please expand a little? I can't solve that

Comment: @Simon: answer expanded.

Comment: How have you replaced the $z_0$ in the $x_n$ expression to give the final expression?

Comment: At $n=0$ $$x_0=\frac{1}{\frac{z_0}{r^0}+\frac{1}{r-1}}$$ holds. That gives $z_0$ in terms of $x_0$.